# HashMap borrow issue when trying to implement find or insert

Tags: rust

I tried to implement own analogue of `find_or_insert` method that looks like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct SomeManager {
    next: i32,
    types: HashMap<i32, i32>,
}

impl SomeManager {
    pub fn get_type<'a>(&'a mut self, k: i32) -> &'a i32 {
        match self.types.get(&k) {
            Some(ref x) => return *x,
            None => {
                self.types.insert(k, self.next);
                self.next += 1;
                return self.types.get(&k).unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.types` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:13:17
   |
10 |         match self.types.get(&k) {
   |               ---------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
13 |                 self.types.insert(k, self.next);
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
18 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

I know that there are some standard methods that implement this functionality, but I want this method to be as light as possible - it will be called very-very often and almost all of the time the values will already exist.

As I understand it, when we call `self.types.get` we borrow it to scope of **match** statement, so we can't call `self.types.insert` here. I have tried to move methods from **None** branch out of **match** statement, but it also fails.

The only working solution that I found requires invoking `get` twice:

```
pub fn get_type<'a>(&'a mut self, k: i32) -> &'a i32 {
    let is_none = match self.types.get(&k) {
        Some(ref x) => false,
        None => true,
    };
    if is_none {
        self.types.insert(k, self.next);
        self.next += 1;
    }
    self.types.get(&k).unwrap()
}
```

How can I work around such situations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a handful of methods on `HashMap` to achieve these sorts of complex cases. Most notably, for your case, [`HashMap::entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) and [`Entry::or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with):

```
pub fn get_type<'a>(&'a mut self, k: i32) -> &'a i32 {
    self.types.entry(k).or_insert_with(|| {
        let value = self.next;
        self.next += 1;
        value
    })
}
```

In your case, however, there’s the borrow of `self` inside, so that won’t do.

We thus shift the borrow of `self.next` outside of the closure so the compiler can reason about it as disjoint from `self.types`. Problem solved with only one lookup, as it should be.

```
pub fn get_type<'a>(&'a mut self, k: i32) -> &'a i32 {
    let next = &mut self.next;

    self.types.entry(k).or_insert_with(|| {
        let value = *next;
        *next += 1;
        value
    })
}
```

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: observe!

Comment: I didn't know that passing something like `&mut self.path` to a method taking `self` as a receiver is possible. It's really great.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: it’s *not* taking `self`, leastways not the same `self` as in `self.path`; it’s taking `self.types`, making the borrows disjoint.

Comment: For those still coming across this, it seems that these methods no longer exist and that the new way to do this is using the .entry() API, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28512504/3000133

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your first case you're doing *one* lookup when the key exists in the map and *three* when it does not exist. Your last attempt does *two* lookups in either case. This is somewhat prettified version of the latter:

```
pub fn get_type<'a>(&'a mut self, k: i32) -> &'a i32 {
    let contains = self.types.contains_key(&k);
    if !contains {
        self.types.insert(k, self.next);
        self.next += 1;
    }
    self.types.get(&k).unwrap()
}
```

I don't think it is possible to avoid the second lookup without some support from the map's implementation because of borrowing restrictions.

In any case, using the [solution by Chris Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24287973/155423) is superior to the above one (for example, it may be more efficient and in fact require less lookups), so I suggest sticking with it.

Comment: The second solution will be ideal for me, but it also fails to compile  - for some reason it says that previous borrow (in match) ends at the end of the function

Comment: @Mikhail, check this out.

Comment: Returning a reference means that `v`’s lifetime is `'a`, and hence the `self.types` borrow is of lifetime `'a`—the curly braces you put around it won’t help at all.