# How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?

Tags: hashmap, rust, lookup

I'd like to do the following:

- Lookup a `Vec` for a certain key, and store it for later use.
- If it doesn't exist, create an empty `Vec` for the key, but still keep it in the variable.

How to do this efficiently? Naturally I thought I could use `match`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// This code doesn't compile.
let mut map = HashMap::new();
let key = "foo";
let values: &Vec<isize> = match map.get(key) {
    Some(v) => v,
    None => {
        let default: Vec<isize> = Vec::new();
        map.insert(key, default);
        &default
    }
};
```

When I tried it, it gave me errors like:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:11:13
   |
7  |     let values: &Vec<isize> = match map.get(key) {
   |                                     --- immutable borrow occurs here
...
11 |             map.insert(key, default);
   |             ^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
15 | }
   | - immutable borrow ends here
```

I ended up with doing something like this, but I don't like the fact that it performs the lookup twice (`map.contains_key` and `map.get`):

```
// This code does compile.
let mut map = HashMap::new();
let key = "foo";
if !map.contains_key(key) {
    let default: Vec<isize> = Vec::new();
    map.insert(key, default);
}
let values: &Vec<isize> = match map.get(key) {
    Some(v) => v,
    None => {
        panic!("impossiburu!");
    }
};
```

Is there a safe way to do this with just one `match`?

Answer (score 242, accepted):

The [`entry` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) is designed for this. In manual form, it might look like

```rust
let values = match map.entry(key) {
    Entry::Occupied(o) => o.into_mut(),
    Entry::Vacant(v) => v.insert(default),
};
```

One can use the briefer form via [`Entry::or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with):

```rust
let values = map.entry(key).or_insert_with(|| default);
```

If `default` is already computed, or if it's OK/cheap to compute even when it isn't inserted, you can use [`Entry::or_insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert):

```rust
let values = map.entry(key).or_insert(default);
```

If the `HashMap`'s value implements `Default`, you can use [`Entry::or_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_default), although you may need to provide some type hints:

```rust
let values = map.entry(key).or_default();
```

Comment: Thanks for a swift anser! Now I've learned I should look into a little deep down to the documents.

Comment: the issue with entry() is, that you always have to clone the key, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Pascalius you could make your key type `&T` (if the keys outlive the map, e.g. static strings) or `Rc<T>` instead of `T` -- but it's not pretty in either case

Comment: @Pascalius: you can use `v.key()` in the expression for `default`, and then it will get a reference to the key as it exists in the hashmap, so you may avoid a clone this way

Comment: @Pascalius Note that since 1.50 there's [or_insert_with_key](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with_key)

Answer (score 3):

I've used [huon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28512504/155423) and implemented it as a trait:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::Hash;

pub trait InsertOrGet<K: Eq + Hash, V: Default> {
    fn insert_or_get(&mut self, item: K) -> &mut V;
}

impl<K: Eq + Hash, V: Default> InsertOrGet<K, V> for HashMap<K, V> {
    fn insert_or_get(&mut self, item: K) -> &mut V {
        return match self.entry(item) {
            std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Occupied(o) => o.into_mut(),
            std::collections::hash_map::Entry::Vacant(v) => v.insert(V::default()),
        };
    }
}
```

Then I can do:

```rust
use crate::utils::hashmap::InsertOrGet;

let new_or_existing_value: &mut ValueType = my_map.insert_or_get(my_key.clone());
```

Comment: Why don't you use `my_map.entry(my_key).or_default();` instead?  You dont need this trait.

Answer (score 0):

Just to present an alternative to the [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) solution in [@huon's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28512504/19770795), you could do this in two steps using the relatively new [`try_insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.try_insert) method, which only inserts the value, if the key is not yet occupied.

```rust
let _ = map.try_insert(key, Vec::new());  // May or may not insert the empty vector.
let values = map.get_mut(key).unwrap();   // Guaranteed to be occupied now.
```

(Full [Playground example here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3a104f08d818fb5438f7a4a84ab22f16).)

As of today, the `try_insert` method is still available in ***nightly*** Rust only, behind the [`map_try_insert`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82766) feature gate.

Ironically, it is currently [implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e51e98dde6a60637b6a71b8105245b629ac3fe77/library/std/src/collections/hash/map.rs#L1129-L1134) using the `Entry` API itself. Though in OP's case I would probably prefer using `entry` directly with `or_default` as in the accepted answer myself.