# cannot borrow `self.hash` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make this work

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Test1 {
    total: u32,
    hash: HashMap<u32, u32>,
}

impl Test1 {
    fn new() -> Test1 {
        Test1 {
            total: 0,
            hash: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add(&mut self) -> u32 {
        self.total += 1;
        self.total
    }

    fn get_or_create(&mut self, id: u32) -> u32 {
        match self.hash.get(&id) {
            Some(value) => *value,
            None => {
                let value = self.add();
                self.hash.insert(id, value);
                value
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut test = Test1::new();
    println!("{:?}", test.get_or_create(1));
    println!("{:?}", test.get_or_create(1));
}
```

(playpen)[http://is.gd/hDLEaL]

but I get

```
<anon>:25:33: 25:37 error: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because `self.hash` is also borrowed as immutable [E0502]
```

removing pattern matching doesn't address the problem, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Try to change `match self.hash.get(&id) {` into `match self.hash.get(&id).cloned() {` and `*value` to `value`

Comment: Thanks, it has a lot of sense. It works!!

Comment: That's because `get` returns `Option<&u32>` but you actually don't need that borrowed reference but only value. So `cloned()` transforms `Option<&T>` into `Option<T>` and releases borrow.

Comment: There is a better idiom for what you are trying to do, `.entry().or_insert()`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry

Comment: [**Highly** relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28512394/155423).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Update

With the addition of [Non-Lexical Lifetimes](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/12/06/Rust-1.31-and-rust-2018.html#non-lexical-lifetimes) in Rust, this problem should no longer be an issue if you're using [1.31.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1310-2018-12-06) with Rust 2018 edition and [1.36.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1360-2019-07-04) with Rust 2015 edition.

## Original Answer

This is a problem with the current state of Rust, where borrows are always lexical. That is, they last the entire `{}` or block scope. In a `match` expression, the borrow performed on `self` continues into the `Some` and `None` blocks. The simplest way to solve this problem is to use an `if let` statement. It provides pattern matching, and allows you to use `self` in both blocks.

## [Code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=a89a382b24ad89cdbc95810cf1e76215)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Test1 {
    total: u32,
    hash: HashMap<u32, u32>,
}

impl Test1 {
    fn new() -> Test1 {
        Test1 {
            total: 0,
            hash: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add(&mut self) -> u32 {
        self.total += 1;
        self.total
    }

    fn get_or_create(&mut self, id: u32) -> u32 {
        if let Some(&value) = self.hash.get(&id) {
            value
        } else {
            let value = self.add();
            self.hash.insert(id, value);
            value
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut test = Test1::new();
    println!("{:?}", test.get_or_create(1));
    println!("{:?}", test.get_or_create(1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I thought I was going crazy.