# Not all control paths return a value?

Tags: rust

Here's my code to find the indices of two numbers such that they add up to a specific target:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn two_sum(nums: &[i32], target: i32) -> [usize;2] {
    let mut map: HashMap<i32, usize>  = HashMap::new();

   for i in  0..nums.len() {
        let want = target - nums[i];
        match map.get(&nums[i]) {
            Some(&seen) => return [seen, i],
            _ =>  map.insert(want, i),
            };
    }

    [0usize, 0usize];
}

fn main() {
    let nums = [1,3,7,4];
    let res = two_sum(&nums, 10);
    println! ("{},{}", res[0], res[1]);
}
```

Which throws this error:

```
src/bin/2sum.rs:3:1: 15:2 error: not all control paths return a value [E0269]
src/bin/2sum.rs:3 fn two_sum(nums: &[i32], target: i32) -> [usize;2] {
src/bin/2sum.rs:4     let mut map: HashMap<i32, usize>  = HashMap::new();
src/bin/2sum.rs:5 
src/bin/2sum.rs:6     for i in  0..nums.len() {
src/bin/2sum.rs:7         let want = target - nums[i];
src/bin/2sum.rs:8         match map.get(&nums[i]) {
              ...
src/bin/2sum.rs:3:1: 15:2 help: run `rustc --explain E0269` to see a detailed     explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can make all return paths return a value, in this case via removing the semicolon after `[0usize, 0usize]`

Comment: Did you "run `rustc --explain E0269` to see a detailed explanation" as suggested by the compiler?

Comment: You would probably be interested in [How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28512394/155423).

Comment: The errors are also listed online: [E0269](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0269)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the semicolon after `[0usize, 0usize]` ([this is idiomatic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/functions.html)) or add a `return [0usize, 0usize]`.

To improve your code you can return an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html). Also, in this case, it is better to return a tuple.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn two_sum(nums: &[i32], target: i32) -> Option<(usize, usize)> {
    let mut map: HashMap<i32, usize> = HashMap::new();

    for i in 0..nums.len() {
        let want = target - nums[i];
        match map.get(&nums[i]) {
            Some(&seen) => return Some((seen, i)),
            _ => map.insert(want, i),
        };
    }

    None
}

fn main() {
    let nums = [1, 3, 7, 4];
    let res = two_sum(&nums, 10);
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```