# How can I specify the type of the Some parameter in Rust?

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

I am working on a program in Rust and I am getting stuck on `match`. I currently have

```
extern crate regex;

use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let s = "";

    let re = regex::Regex::new(r"[^A-Za-z0-9\w'").unwrap();
    let s = re.split(s).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let mut h: HashMap<String, u32> = HashMap::new();
    for x in s {
        match h.get(x) {
            Some(i) => h.entry(x.to_string()).or_insert_with(i + 1),
            None => h.entry(x.to_string()).or_insert_with(1),
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run this I get a whole litany of errors, including

```
error: the trait bound `u32: std::ops::FnOnce<()>` is not satisfied [E0277]
            Some(i) => h.entry(x.to_string()).or_insert_with(i + 1),
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

and I'm not exactly sure where to go with this.

Comment: See also [How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28512394/155423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `or_with` family of functions expect a function that returns the values as a parameter. You want [`.or_insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/btree_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert), which directly expects the value:

```
let re = regex::Regex::new(r"[^A-Za-z0-9\w'").unwrap();
let s = re.split(s).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
let mut h: HashMap<String, u32> = HashMap::new();
for x in s {
    match h.get(x) {
      Some(i) => h.entry(x.to_string()).or_insert(i + 1),
      None    => h.entry(x.to_string()).or_insert(1),
    }
}
```

Anyway, you are missing the point of the `Entry` API:

```
let re = regex::Regex::new(r"[^A-Za-z0-9\w'").unwrap();
let s = re.split(s).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
let mut h: HashMap<String, u32> = HashMap::new();
for x in s {
    match h.entry(x.to_string()) {
      Entry::Vacant(v)   => {
          v.insert(1);
      },
      Entry::Occupied(o) => {
          *o.into_mut() += 1;
      },
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use `or_insert` I get `mismatched types: expected \`()\` found \`&mut u32\``

Comment: That's because `or_insert` returns `&mut _` but the loop body must have a unit type. I've edited my answer anyway.

Comment: Thank you! The `Entry` API is fantastic.

Comment: I think you really want `*h.entry(x.to_string()).or_insert(0) += 1;`

Comment: @EliSadoff: I was blown away when Gankro unveiled it :)