# How do you make the value of a Some returned from HashMap::get mutable?

Tags: rust

I can't figure out how to modify the value returned by `Some`:

```
fn add_employee(
    employees: &mut HashMap<String, Vec<String>>,
    employee_name: &String,
    department_name: &String,
) {
    match employees.get(department_name) {
        Some(members) => {
            members.push(employee_name.clone()); // what I want, but it doesn't work
        }
        None => {}
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*members` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:13
   |
10 |             members.push(employee_name.clone());
   |             ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Comment: Prefer using an `if let` instead of a one-armed `match`. [Accept `&str` instead of `&String`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423). My intuition says you will really want the [entry API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28512394/155423).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`get_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) instead of `get()`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'm working through the docs yet somehow missed this.