# Using Entry with a &str even though the key is String in Rust?

Tags: string, hashmap, rust

I'm working on a problem similar to the one in [How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512394/how-to-lookup-from-and-insert-into-a-hashmap-efficiently/28512504#28512504). I have a map with `String` keys and I want to write a function that returns the value for a key if it exists, or calculates and inserts it if it doesn't.

From the answer to that question, I understand that the proper way to do this is to use an `Entry`. So I wrote this:

```
fn get_or_calculate(&self, key: &str) -> u64 {
    match self.map.entry(key) {
        Entry::Occupied(o) => o.get(),
        Entry::Vacant(v) => v.insert(2 + 2),
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that I can no longer use `&str` to lookup values. While `map.get()` happily accepts a `&str`, `map.entry()` needs a `String` that it can take ownership of:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:15:30
   |
15 |         match self.map.entry(key) {
   |                              ^^^
   |                              |
   |                              expected struct `std::string::String`, found &str
   |                              help: try using a conversion method: `key.to_string()`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::string::String`
              found type `&str`
```

I could just use `to_string()`, but I understand that may be costly. It feels a bit unnecessary - since the `Entry` doesn't outlive my function it would not need to take ownership of the string.

Is there any way to use `Entry` with `&str` even though the key is `String`? Can I somehow rewrite the code without using an `Entry`?