# How to group by vector's key?

Tags: rust

I want to group a vector by key when the key is a vector.

```rust
struct Document {
    categories: Vec<String>,
    body: String
}
```

```rust
let docs = vec![
    Document {categories: ["rust".to_string(), body: "doc1".to_string()]},
    Document {categories: ["clojure".to_string()], body: "doc2".to_string()},
    Document {categories: ["java".to_string()], body: "doc3".to_string()},
    Document {categories: ["rust".to_string(), "clojure".to_string], body: "doc4".to_string()}
];
```

I want to return like below `(category_key, documents)`

```
"rust" => [doc1, doc4]  
"clojure" => [doc2, doc4]  
"java" => [doc3]
```

Comment: And what did you try, this look like a code request.

Comment: The code you have provided is not syntactically valid Rust code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a novice at Rust and this was a challenge for me

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

let result = docs.iter().fold(
    HashMap::new(),
    |mut init: HashMap<String, Vec<String>>, ref item| {
        for category in &item.categories {
            let item_body = item.body.clone();

            let new_vector: Vec<String> = init
                .remove(category)
                .map(|mut val| {
                    val.push(item_body.clone());
                    val
                })
                .unwrap_or(vec![item_body.clone()])
                .to_vec();
            init.insert(category.clone(), new_vector);
        }

        init
    },
);
```

I'm sure this code can be simplified.

Comment: [How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28512394/155423)

Comment: Your `ref` is unneeded; you should use `unwrap_or_else`; there's no apparent reason to do any cloning. [How I'd write it](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2f2f1aa1b0f239ed08f34018f2f544d1)