# What's the best practice of `insert or update` operation in Rust's HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I'm looking for a best practice for the `insert-or-update` operation, because it is very commonly used, I think we need to optimize both its writing style and efficiency.

Assume the following scenario: I got a `hashmap`

```rust
let classes: HashMap(String, HashSet<String>) = HashMap::new()
```

which is used to store students and whos classes.

The data is expected to be in the following form:

```rust
{ key: "ClassA", value: {"Bob", "Marry", "Jack"}},
{ key: "ClassB", value: {"Lee", "Tom"}},
```

Now I got a new set of data of a student and his/her class, let's take:

```rust
{ name: "Alice", class: "ClassC"}
```

Since I'm not sure if the class already appears in the `classes` HashMap, I need to figure out whether it exists first, if it is, I'm going to update the value, and if it's not, I'm going to add a new `key->value` pair.

What's the correct way to do it with out any unnecessary move or copy? Based on other answers, I tried to use `std::collections::hash_map::Entry` but I failed.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512394/how-to-lookup-from-and-insert-into-a-hashmap-efficiently , also see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html and search for "doesn't already exist". Questions also generally tend to fair better when describing "but I failed" in relevant detail.

Answer (score 15):

The idiomatic way to use that map would be something like this:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut classes: HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> = HashMap::new();
    
    let e = classes.entry(String::from("ClassA"));
    e.or_default().insert(String::from("Alice"));

    let e = classes.entry(String::from("ClassA"));
    e.or_default().insert(String::from("Bob"));
    
    dbg!(&classes);
}
```

The [`HashMap::entry()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) function returns an `Entry` value, that represents either the value contained in the map or the place it would be if it were in the map. This `Entry` type has a lot of functions to access the contained value, and create it if needed. In your case the easiest function to use is [`or_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_default) that creates a default value (an empty set) if the value is not yet in the map.

Then, since you have a mutable reference to the set inside the map, just insert the desired value.

Comment: Yes, I think this should be a best practice if the target value type implements the `default` trait, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get an insert or update behavior I would do it in this fluent way

```
classes.entry(String::from("ClassC"))
    .or_default()
    .insert(String::from("Alice"));
```

A test example which covers your scenario

```
#[test]
fn test(){
    // Arrange
    let mut classes: HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> = HashMap::from([
        (String::from("ClassA"), HashSet::from([String::from("Bob"), String::from("Marry"), String::from("Jack")])),
        (String::from("ClassB"), HashSet::from([String::from("Lee"), String::from("Tom")])),
    ]);
    let class_c = String::from("ClassC");
    let alice = String::from("Alice");

    // Act
    classes.entry(class_c.clone())
        .or_default()
        .insert(alice.clone());

    // Assert
    let contains_class = classes.contains_key(&class_c);
    let contains_alice = classes.get(&class_c)
        .unwrap().contains(&alice);
    assert_eq!(true, contains_class);
    assert_eq!(true, contains_alice);
}
```