# How to get value from HashMap or create new one in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, hashmap

I am wondering what would be an elegant way to either get an existing value from a HashMap or create a new one and assign it to a variable.

I was thinking about something like this ...

```
struct Test {
    name: String,
    valid: bool
}

    let tests: HashMap<String, Test> = HashMap::new();

    let key = String::from("a");

    let test = match tests.get(&key) {
        Some(t) => t,
        None => {
            let t = Test {
                name: key,
                valid: false,
            };

           &t
        }
    };
```

This results to the expected error

```
error[E0597]: `t` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:33:12
   |
33 |            &t
   |            ^^
   |            |
   |            borrowed value does not live long enough
   |            borrow later used here
34 |         }
   |         - `t` dropped here while still borrowed
```

A kind of workaround is to do this ...

```
    let t;
    let test = match tests.get(&key) {
        Some(node) => node,
        None => {
            t = Test {
                name: key,
                valid: false,
            };

           &t
        }
    };
```

It seems to me a little bit unhandy just to introduce the extra variable t in advance to be able to shift out the reference of the allocated structure for the case the instance of the structure is not found in the HashMap.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Assuming you want to add the entry into the map, consider the [`entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) API, eg `let test = tests.entry(key).or_insert(Test { name: key, value: false });`.

Comment: As an aside, it's a little odd to store a copy of the key in the value.  Perhaps you're actually after a `HashSet` where the `Hash` impl for `Test` is based only on its `name` field?

Comment: @eggyal this answered my question. If you want me to accept it as answer, please post it as answer, so that I am able to mark it as answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512394/how-to-lookup-from-and-insert-into-a-hashmap-efficiently)