# Add or increment value in HashMap in Rust

Tags: rust, hashmap

I am new to Rust and recently started learning. I wrote a simple program which does the following.

1. Read a text file
2. Split the words and store them in a HashMap with their occurrence count
3. Iterate over the map and print the word and occurrence count

```
use std::io;
use std::env;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let path = env::args().nth(1).unwrap();
    let contents = read_file(path);
    let map = count_words(contents);
    print(map);
}

fn read_file(path: String) -> (String){
    let contents =  fs::read_to_string(path).unwrap();
    return contents;
}

fn count_words(contents: String) -> (HashMap<String, i32>){
    let split = contents.split(&[' ', '\n'][..]);
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for w in split{
        if map.get(w) == None{
            map.insert(w.to_owned(), 1);
        }
        let count = map.get(w);
        map.insert(w.to_owned(), count + 1); // error here
    }
    return map;
}

fn print(map: HashMap<String, i32>){
    println!("Occurences..");

    for (key, value) in map.iter() {
        println!("{key}: {value}");
    }
}
```

I am able to read the file and add the words into a HashMap and print. However, while trying to add or increment, I get below error.

> error[E0369]: cannot add `{integer}` to `Option<&{integer}>`   -->
> src\main.rs:27:40    | 27 |         map.insert(w.to_owned(), count +
> 1);    |                                  ----- ^ - {integer}    |
> |    |                                  Option<&{integer}>

I know this approach should work in other languages like Java, C# etc. but unsure about how it should work in Rust.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512394/how-to-lookup-from-and-insert-into-a-hashmap-efficiently answer your question?

Comment: You should use pattern matching in order to get from an `Option<{integer}>` to an `{integer}`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lookup from and insert into a HashMap efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512394/how-to-lookup-from-and-insert-into-a-hashmap-efficiently)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this block:

```rust
if map.get(w) == None{
            map.insert(w.to_owned(), 1);
        }
        let count = map.get(w);
        map.insert(w.to_owned(), count + 1); // error here
```

`map.get(w)` gives you an `Option<w>` ([doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get));

You seem to know this to some extent, as you check if it's a `None` earlier - the other possibility is that it is what you want - a `Some(w)` (not just `w`);

You cannot add an `int` to a `Some`, as the compiler tells you - you have to take "the `w`" (the count integer) out of the `Some`.

---

You can `unwrap` ([doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/option_unwrap.html)), though it is not advisable.

---

You can use [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html):

```rust
match map.get(&w) {
    Some(count) => { map.insert(w, count + 1); }
    None => { map.insert(w, 1); }
}
```

Or, written differently:

```rust
if let Some(count) = map.get(&w) {
    map.insert(w, count + 1);
} else {
    map.insert(w, 1);
};
```

---

Or, better yet, you can use the [Entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html), which turns it into a simple one liner:

```rust
    *map.entry(w.to_owned()).or_default() += 1;
```

Comment: The if-else check for Some worked but the one line threw an error '^^^ expected struct `String`, found `&str`' in the return map statement

Comment: Edited your one liner with some correction and now it's working.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Just like inserting into a map wants an owned String, so does the `.entry()` call, yes, as it will potentially also insert. Though you edited out `.or_default()` for `.or_insert(0)`, which are equivalent. A default on a number type would be 0. I personally prefer `or_default()`, as I think it is relatively obvious what is happening, but if you want to be verbose - not a fault.

Comment: Approaches with `match` and `if let Some...` probably will not work because of: cannot borrow `map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable