# How to work around self borrowing with map .or_insert_with? Rust (1.11)

Tags: dictionary, rust

This snippet

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo {
    local_ids: HashMap<i32, i32>,
    last_id: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self, external_id: i32) {
        let id = self.local_ids
                     .entry(external_id)
                     .or_insert_with(||{self.last_id += 1; self.last_id});
    }
}
```

Doesn't work because we can't borrow self twice

```
error: closure requires unique access to `self` but `self.local_ids` is already borrowed [E0500]
```

Is this possible to fix without a second key lookup?

---

This is very similar to [Rust: HashMap borrow issue when trying to implement find or insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287434/rust-hashmap-borrow-issue-when-trying-to-implement-find-or-insert), but the API has changed substantially.

The find_with_or_insert_with answer from above doesn't appear to map to the current api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the closure captures `self`, whereas it only needs to capture a mutable reference to the `last_id` field.

Rust allows us to take independent mutable borrows on distinct fields, so we can use that to our advantage and pass a mutable reference to the `last_id` field to the closure.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo {
    local_ids: HashMap<i32, i32>,
    last_id: i32,
}

impl Foo {
    fn foo(&mut self, external_id: i32) {
        let last_id = &mut self.last_id;
        let id = self.local_ids
                     .entry(external_id)
                     .or_insert_with(|| { *last_id += 1; *last_id });
    }
}
```

When we use the expression `self.last_id` in the closure, the closure captures `self` directly, but Rust doesn't realize that the borrows are independent, so we need to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks! 

Is it at all a new development that you can borrow fields separately?

Comment: No, I think it's been possible for a long time.