# How to eliminate partial move when calling map on an iterator

Tags: collections, rust, borrow-checker

I have a simple (I thought it should be) task to `map` values contained in a `Vec` and produce another `Vec`:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Value(u32);
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Id(u32);

struct ValuesInfo {
    values: Vec<Value>,
    name: String,
    id: Id
}

struct ValueInfo{
    value: Value,
    name: String,
    id: Id
}

fn extend_values(v: Vec<ValuesInfo>) -> Vec<Vec<ValueInfo>> {
    v.into_iter().map(|values_info|{
        values_info.values.into_iter().map(|value|{
            ValueInfo{
                value,
                name: values_info.name.clone(),
                id: values_info.id.clone()
            }
        }).collect::<Vec<ValueInfo>>()
    }).collect::<Vec<Vec<ValueInfo>>>()
}
```

[Playground permalink](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d154acfb0daf2594e0c0d2b0da54e79)

Here I have a partial move error looking as

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `values_info`
   --> src/lib.rs:20:44
    |
20  |         values_info.values.into_iter().map(|value|{
    |                            -----------     ^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after partial move
    |                            |
    |                            `values_info.values` moved due to this method call
...
23  |                 name: values_info.name.clone(),
    |                       ----------- borrow occurs due to use in closure
    |
note: this function consumes the receiver `self` by taking ownership of it, which moves `values_info.values`
    = note: move occurs because `values_info.values` has type `std::vec::Vec<Value>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I need this partial `move` because this is what the task is about. Is there any workaround to solve the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the 2018 edition of Rust, closures always capture entire variables by name. So the closure passed to the inner `map` would take a reference to `values_info`, which is not valid because `values_info` has already been partially moved (even though the closure does not need access to the part that was moved).

#### Rust 2021+

Since Rust 2021, captures borrow (or move) only the minimal set of fields required in the body of the closure. This makes the original code work as you expected¹, so you can make the error go away by simply [changing the playground edition to 2021](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d154acfb0daf2594e0c0d2b0da54e79). See the [edition guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/disjoint-capture-in-closures.html) for more.

#### Rust 2015 & 2018

In previous editions, you can do it manually: destructure the `ValuesInfo` *first*, and only capture `name` and `id` inside the closure. You can destructure the `ValuesInfo` as soon as you get it, in the argument list of the outer closure:

```
fn extend_values(v: Vec<ValuesInfo>) -> Vec<Vec<ValueInfo>> {
    v.into_iter()
        .map(|ValuesInfo { values, name, id }| {
        //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ like `let ValuesInfo { values, name, id } = values_info;`
            values
                .into_iter()
                .map(|value| ValueInfo {
                    value,
                    name: name.clone(),
                    id: id.clone(),
                })
                .collect()
        })
        .collect()
}
```

### See also

- [How to use struct self in member method closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48717833/3650362)
- [HashMap borrow issue when trying to implement find or insert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24287434/3650362) is solved using a similar trick.

---

¹ Unless `ValuesInfo` implements `Drop`, which makes any destructuring or partial move unsound.

Answer (score 4):

Naming `values_info` in the closure will borrow it
as a whole although it is already partially moved
(as told by the error message).
You should borrow the members you need beforehand.

```rust
        let name=&values_info.name;
        let id=&values_info.id;
        values_info.values.into_iter().map(|value|{
            ValueInfo{
                value,
                name: name.clone(),
                id: id.clone(),
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

```rust
#[derive(Clone)] //you could derive Copy. u32 is generally cheap to copy
struct Value(u32);
#[derive(Clone)] //you could derive Copy
struct Id(u32);

struct ValuesInfo {
    values: Vec<Value>,
    name: String,
    id: Id
}

struct ValueInfo{
    value: Value,
    name: String,
    id: Id
}

//No need to consume v. Not sure if it will come in handy
fn extend_values(v: &Vec<ValuesInfo>) -> Vec<Vec<ValueInfo>> {

    //Use into_iter only if you need the ownership of the content of the array
    // which I don't think you need because you are cloning every value of ValueInfo
    //except for value which is already cheep to copy/clone
    v.iter().map(|values_info|{
        values_info.values.iter().map(|value|{
            ValueInfo{
                value: value.clone(),
                name: values_info.name.clone(),
                id: values_info.id.clone()
            }
        }).collect::<Vec<ValueInfo>>()
    }).collect::<Vec<Vec<ValueInfo>>>()
}
```

That said, if you really don't want to copy/clone `Value` you need to `clone` name and `id` before hand. The compiler stops you from using `values_info.name.clone()` because the function `into_iter` already consumed `values_info`.
The code would look something like this if you really don't want to copy `Value`

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Value(u32);
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Id(u32);

struct ValuesInfo {
    values: Vec<Value>,
    name: String,
    id: Id
}

struct ValueInfo{
    value: Value,
    name: String,
    id: Id
}

fn extend_values(v: Vec<ValuesInfo>) -> Vec<Vec<ValueInfo>> {
    v.into_iter().map(|values_info|{
        let name = values_info.name.clone();
        let id = values_info.id.clone();
        values_info.values.into_iter().map(
        |value| {
            ValueInfo{
                value,
                name: name.clone(),
                id: id.clone(), 
            }
        }).collect::<Vec<ValueInfo>>()
    }).collect::<Vec<Vec<ValueInfo>>>()
}
```

Comment: `name` and `id` are cloned twice. The first clone could be avoided with an immutable borrow.

Comment: You cannot borrow `name` and `id` and use them after `into_iter` is called. `values_info` at that point is consumed. My approach look very similar to yours. The amount of `clone` calls is the same and there is no implicit copy.

Comment: Good catch @trentcl! I should not be saying "derive Copy instead"

Comment: You are correct that this answer has the same number of clones, but only because @prog-fh's solution also does two more than necessary! `let name = &values_info.name;` would work as well. Cloning outside the closure is a technique generally useful for `move` closures to eliminate references to the environment; you don't need to do that here.

Comment: you are both right, my first clone was the remaining of a first attempt, I thought I had removed it at the beginning, and borrowing this clone was obviously a total non-sense. Sorry for the confusion.